# Get selectize.js original element

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm using selectize.js something like this:

```
$( 'select' ).selectize( {
    onChange: function( value ) {
        // how to get original element here?
    }
} );
```

There's several `select` elements on the page.
I want to get `select` on which the event occurred inside of `onChange`.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `$(this)[0]` inside the onChange. Once `this` is the selectize object by itself

```
$( 'select' ).selectize( {
    onChange: function( value ) {
      var obj = $(this)[0];
      alert(obj.$input["0"].id);
    }
} );
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pv76m1na/)

Comment: `$(this)[0]` is exactly the same as just `this`. You can just call `alert(this.$input.prop('id'))` or `alert(this.$input[0].id)`

Answer (score -1):

you can get all user events from onInitialize :

```
$('select').selectize({
         onInitialize: function (selectize) {
            selectize.on('change', function (value) {
                var elem = this.$input[0];
                console.log('on "change" event fired > ' + elem.id);
              });
            selectize.on('focus', function () {
                console.log('on "focus" event fired');
            });
            selectize.on('dropdown_open', function () {
                console.log('on "dropdown_open" event fired');
            });
        }
 }
```